# how to take input of an int variable and write it to a file?

Tags: c++, oop, fwrite

I know how to initialize an int variable and write it to a file but how do you take this int variable as input from user, write it to a file and then read it?
I think it should be done as follows but when I open the file to which I'm writing it has just the string type variable "name" and some non-human readable code not the int variable "age".
 here program is the name of class that has attributes name and age.

```
   void save()
{
    ofstream out;
    out.open("program.txt", ios::out | ios::binary | ios::app);
    if (!out)
        cout << "cannot save";
    else
    {
        program *temp = first;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            out.write( (char)*temp, sizeof(program));
            temp = temp->next;

        }
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code consistently and strip anything not necessary. Also, add the C++ tag to your question for proper visibility.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing to the file a custom object type in binary mode. What you are seeing is a file with objects of the type `program`.

If you want a human-readable file output, try writing to the file without `ios::binary`. But remember you cannot write objects to the file. You must take individual members in the object and write them.

Hope I'm making sense.

Check this program as an example. This works.

```
# include <string>
# include <fstream>
# include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct program {
    int age;
    string name;
    program* next;
};

program* first = new program;

void save()
{
    ofstream out;
    out.open("program.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
    if (!out)
        cout << "cannot save";
    else
    {
        program *temp = first;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            out<<temp->age<<" "<<temp->name<<"\n";
            temp = temp->next;

        }
        out.close();
    }
}

int main()
{
    first->age=10; first->name="Alice"; 
    first->next = new program;
    first->next->age=20; first->next->name="Bob"; first->next->next = NULL;       
    save();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Zeb : I've edited the answer to include a sample program. This is how you write.